# method isn't taking long long int value shows error

Tags: c++, c, tree, binary-search-tree

I am creating an simple program in which I am using `long long int` but I got compiler error. Please help me to resolve this error.

> Error] conflicting types for `countTrees`

I got error on this line

```
long long int countTrees(long long int numKeys)
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int n;
        scanf("%lld", &n);
        long long int result = countTrees(n);
        printf("%lld\n",result);        
    }

return 0;
}  
long long int countTrees(long long int numKeys) {

  if (numKeys <=1) {
    return(1);
  }
  else {
    long long int sum = 0;
    long long int left,right,root;

    for (root=1; root<=numKeys; root++) {
      left = countTrees(root - 1);
      right = countTrees(numKeys - root);

      sum += left*right;
    }

    return(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: Error] conflicting types for 'countTrees'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error, because of the implicit declaration of the `countTrees()` not matching the actual definition.

To clarify "implicit declaration" when a function is called, but the compiler has not seen the function definition yet, it *assumes*  that the function returns `int` and accepts any number (and type) of parameters.

In `C99` and future standards, the *implicit declaration* is made invalid, so a compiler should complain if a function, which is not yet defined (or at least. prototyped, through a forward declaration), is used (called).

To resolve the issue, you can do either

- add a forward declaration of  your function.
- define the function before `main()`.

Comment: result is so big long long int isn't working.any other options??

Comment: @SaketMittal Try `long long unsigned`